# JQuery .toggleClass() two classes at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$('.button').click(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('clicked')
     $('.clicked+span').toggleClass('choice');
});
```

I've just started learning jQuery and I was playing around with some methods. So when the link with class `.button` is clicked, the `toggleClass` adds at the same time the two classes, BUT when I click it again only the `.clicked` is removed. The `.choice` class remains, despite what I thought.
Could someone explain what I'm missing here, and may be how to achieve this - toggle both classes at every click?

**EDIT**

Sorry, here's the [***code***](http://jsfiddle.net/96GZB/) 
The thing I want to achieve is when you click 'a)' for example, the corresponding line gets highlighted in some way.

Comment: Why would it toggle the `choice` class on an element that is not `.clicked`?

Comment: You could use `$(this).toggleClass("clicked choice")`, it will then toggle between clicked and choice assuming the element had one of the two to begin with.

Comment: Can you show us some html?

Comment: +1 to chris, show us some HTML codes please. preferably put it on http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, seeing the code make it clearer.

```
    $('.button').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
        $(this).next('span').toggleClass('choice');
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/96GZB/3/

I think you'd be better off making the span a child of the .button, so you could just set something like this in your stylesheet;

```
.clicked span {
background: blue;
}
```

Then you can do away with the .choice class entirely.

Answer (score 2):

the second time your button is clicked..

```
$('.clicked+span').toggleClass('choice');
```

doesn't find your element because the .clicked class was just removed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to add/remove two classes at once, do something like this:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('clicked choice');

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cAcJX/

Comment: If he did, I believe he would use the `$(this)` selector on both lines.

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what he wants to do or what the second line is for.  Without html we're all trying to read his mind.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to implement single choice question you need something like this:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
                var $this = $(this),
                    wasClicked = $this.hasClass("clicked");

                //remove another selected if any
                $('.clicked').removeClass('clicked')
                             .next().removeClass('choice');
                //mark current as selected if it wasn't
                !wasClicked && $this.addClass("clicked")
                                    .next().addClass('choice');
            });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/96GZB/1/

And for multiple choice question:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
                $(this).toggleClass('clicked')
                       .next().toggleClass('choice');
            });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/96GZB/2/

Comment: wow that is more then I was looking for, but thank you so much! I'm learning a lot for this :)